# OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid when calling subprocess from Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm porting a project to Python3 and I'm running into a unexpected error on Windows:

Basically on Python 3.6 on Windows, each time a process is being created with subprocess, I have this exception:

```
d:\temp\backpack\venv\myvenv_py3.6\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py:1011: in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
d:\temp\backpack\venv\myvenv_py3.6\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py:732: in execute
    **subprocess_kwargs
D:\temp\cpython-3.6.3\Lib\subprocess.py:611: in __init__
    _cleanup()
D:\temp\cpython-3.6.3\Lib\subprocess.py:220: in _cleanup
    res = inst._internal_poll(_deadstate=sys.maxsize)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000004FD53C8>
_deadstate = 9223372036854775807
_WaitForSingleObject = <built-in function WaitForSingleObject>
_WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0, _GetExitCodeProcess = <built-in function GetExitCodeProcess>

    def _internal_poll(self, _deadstate=None,
            _WaitForSingleObject=_winapi.WaitForSingleObject,
            _WAIT_OBJECT_0=_winapi.WAIT_OBJECT_0,
            _GetExitCodeProcess=_winapi.GetExitCodeProcess):
        """Check if child process has terminated.  Returns returncode
                attribute.

                This method is called by __del__, so it can only refer to objects
                in its local scope.

                """
        _log.debug('proc._internal_poll  self.pid=%s  self._handle=%s  self.returncode=%s  self=%s', self.pid, self._handle, self.returncode, self)
        if self.returncode is None:
>           if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
E           OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

D:\temp\cpython-3.6.3\Lib\subprocess.py:1051: OSError
```

It doesn't matter where the `subprocess` call is being created from (in this project it's a lot from the `GitPython` package and from `plumbum`).

This execution occurs under this umbrella: `build script` which invokes `venv/Scripts/coverage run -m pytest -v tests/`. But I've also tried `pytest-cov` with `venv/Scripts/pytest --cov=mypackage --cov-config .coveragerc - tests/`
In terms of reproduction:

- on my Win 7 PC it always **passes** :(
- on a Win 7 virtual machine:

  - it always **fails** when [`<build script>` invokes `venv/Scripts/coverage run -m pytest`]
  - it always **fails** when `coverage run -m pytest` is invoked directly from the venv
  - but it always **passes** when `pytest` is invoked directly from the virtualenv
- on a Win 10 PC it will always **fails**,  no matter if the the `<build script>` is invoked, or if  `coverage` or `pytest` are invoked directly from the venv

The only clue that I've got so far is from this StackOverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43975118
and to be more precise, it's the comments from the first accepted answer that point to something useful related to the `_cleanup` method from the `subprocess` module.

Comment: The answer's from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/40108817/501074 didn't fix the issue.

Comment: what does your code using subprocess actually look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of pause, I quickly found the reason behind this.

It was because of the `GitPython` usage in the project which didn't call `git.Repo.close()` or used `git.Repo` as a context manager.
There is a [warning about this](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython#leakage-of-system-resources) on `GitPython`'s readme.

It was helpful to add logging in `subprocess`'s `_internal_poll` method to know which process (`args`) is the culprit. For `GitPython` it was `git cat-file` ...